# how does the immune system identify allergens? application: varenicline and lobeline

Tags: medications, immune-system, allergy, biochemistry

I'm wondering if we know how the immune system identifies allergens. My biochemistry knowledge is basic so I apologize if I use concepts incorrectly! Specifically, I want to know about the likelihood of having an allergic reaction to something, given an allergy to something else...

I'll clarify the situation with the following example:

Say a person develops an allergy to some molecule, A. Another molecule, B, has a different skeletal structure. A and B are both thought to have a similar mechanisms for the treatment of some medical problem. If a person is allergic to A, are they more likely to be allergic to B?

To make this even more concrete, let's say a person is allergic to varenicline, a synthetic molecule used to treat nicotine addiction. Is that person more likely to be allergic to Lobeline (indian tobacco)? They have different skeletal formulas, but varenicline is an agonist on nicotine acetlycholine receptors, while lobeline is a mixed agonist-antagonist on these receptors. (Maybe this is not relevant?).

Does the fact that both molecules have similar neurochemical mechanisms of action on dopamine receptors, have any implications as to whether the immune system would identify the new molecule as an allergen? What about an allergen, physical or chemical, is it that the immune system is actually ID'ing or remembering?

Disclaimer: I have an allergy to varenicline, and considered taking lobeline until i read they have similar neurochemical mechanisms. I'm not looking for advice, because I am not going to take lobeline. I'm just curious. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Highly recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQGOcOUBi6s) (~7 minutes) for a bit of a starting point. (Incidentally, most of Kurzgesagt's video are pretty awesome.)